The Buddha's contemporaries
I was reading an article about The Samaññaphala Sutta and came across this line: This [sutta] is placed in juxtaposition to the Buddhist view of the teachings of rival philosophical teachers of the time, showing how the Buddha — in contradistinction to the inflexible, party-line approach of his contemporaries — presented his teaching in a way that was pertinent and sensitive to the needs of his listeners.
Who were these "contemporaries" and what were they teaching?

The contemporises are listed in the sutta, as follows:

Purana Kassapa... Then another minister said to the king: "Your majesty, there is
Makkhali Gosala... Your majesty, there is Ajita Kesakambalin... Your
majesty, there is Pakudha Kaccayana... Your majesty, there is Sañjaya
Belatthaputta... Your majesty, there is Nigantha Nataputta, the leader
of a community, the leader of a group, the teacher of a group, honored
and famous, esteemed as holy by the mass of people. He is aged, long
gone forth, advanced in years, in the last phase of life. Your majesty
should visit him. Perhaps, if you visited him, he would enlighten and
bring peace to your mind."

The sutta then explains what they each teach, such as in the case of Purana Kassapa:

Purana Kassapa said to me, 'Great king, in acting or getting others to
act, in mutilating or getting others to mutilate, in torturing or
getting others to torture, in inflicting sorrow or in getting others
to inflict sorrow, in tormenting or getting others to torment, in
intimidating or getting others to intimidate, in taking life, taking
what is not given, breaking into houses, plundering wealth, committing
burglary, ambushing highways, committing adultery, speaking falsehood
— one does no evil. If with a razor-edged disk one were to turn all
the living beings on this earth to a single heap of flesh, a single
pile of flesh, there would be no evil from that cause, no coming of
evil. Even if one were to go along the right bank of the Ganges,
killing and getting others to kill, mutilating and getting others to
mutilate, torturing and getting others to torture, there would be no
evil from that cause, no coming of evil. Even if one were to go along
the left bank of the Ganges, giving and getting others to give, making
sacrifices and getting others to make sacrifices, there would be no
merit from that cause, no coming of merit. Through generosity,
self-control, restraint, and truthful speech there is no merit from
that cause, no coming of merit.'

Then Makkhali Gosala:

Makkhali Gosala said to me, 'Great king, there is no cause, no
requisite condition, for the defilement of beings. Beings are defiled
without cause, without requisite condition. There is no cause, no
requisite condition, for the purification of beings. Beings are
purified without cause, without requisite condition. There is nothing
self-caused, nothing other-caused, nothing human-caused. There is no
strength, no effort, no human energy, no human endeavor. All living
beings, all life, all beings, all souls are powerless, devoid of
strength, devoid of effort. Subject to the changes of fate,
serendipity, and nature, they are sensitive to pleasure and pain in
the six great classes of birth.

Next is Ajita Kesakambalin:

Ajita Kesakambalin said to me, 'Great king, there is nothing given,
nothing offered, nothing sacrificed. There is no fruit or result of
good or bad actions. There is no this world, no next world, no mother,
no father, no spontaneously reborn beings; no brahmans or
contemplatives who, faring rightly and practicing rightly, proclaim
this world and the next after having directly known and realized it
for themselves. A person is a composite of four primary elements. At
death, the earth (in the body) returns to and merges with the
(external) earth-substance. The fire returns to and merges with the
external fire-substance. The liquid returns to and merges with the
external liquid-substance. The wind returns to and merges with the
external wind-substance. The sense-faculties scatter into space. Four
men, with the bier as the fifth, carry the corpse. Its eulogies are
sounded only as far as the charnel ground. The bones turn
pigeon-colored. The offerings end in ashes. Generosity is taught by
idiots. The words of those who speak of existence after death are
false, empty chatter. With the break-up of the body, the wise and the
foolish alike are annihilated, destroyed. They do not exist after
death.'

Next is Pakudha Kaccayana:

Pakudha Kaccayana said to me, 'Great king, there are these seven
substances — unmade, irreducible, uncreated, without a creator,
barren, stable as a mountain-peak, standing firm like a pillar — that
do not alter, do not change, do not interfere with one another, are
incapable of causing one another pleasure, pain, or both pleasure and
pain. Which seven? The earth-substance, the liquid-substance, the
fire-substance, the wind-substance, pleasure, pain, and the soul as
the seventh. These are the seven substances — unmade, irreducible,
uncreated, without a creator, barren, stable as a mountain-peak,
standing firm like a pillar — that do not alter, do not change, do not
interfere with one another, and are incapable of causing one another
pleasure, pain, or both pleasure and pain.
"'And among them there is no killer nor one who causes killing, no
hearer nor one who causes hearing, no cognizer nor one who causes
cognition. When one cuts off [another person's] head, there is no one
taking anyone's life. It is simply between the seven substances that
the sword passes.'

Note: not all that is described above is different to the teachings of the Buddha. There is contained some very minor similarities in places.

This would be the refutation of Makkhali Gosala's view: "When one falls back on what was done in the past as being essential, monks, there is no desire, no effort [at the thought], 'This should be done. This shouldn't be done.' When one can't pin down as a truth or reality what should & shouldn't be done, one dwells bewildered & unprotected. One cannot righteously refer to oneself as a contemplative. This was my first righteous refutation of those brahmans & contemplatives who hold to such teachings, such views." -AN 3.61

@dhammadhatu Thanks for taking the time to answer my question so thoroughly!
